# Restricted-source polyglot string

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source, polyglot

Your goal is to write a program that prints the string `abc` in two languages. However, while the full code will print `abc` in one language (we'll call it Language 1), the other one (Language 2) must print `abc` if (and only if) every other character is skipped starting from the second character. If the full code is run in language 2, it must throw an error. If the skipped code is run in language 1, likewise, it must throw an error.

## Rules and Clarification

- Trailing newlines are allowed.
- Output must be lowercase.
- "Run" means compiled for compiled languages.
- We will define "throwing an error" as outputting nothing to STDOUT and something to STDERR.

## Test Cases

```
Language 1: 12345 -> abc
Language 1: 135 -> error
Language 2: 135 -> abc
Language 2: 12345 -> error
```

## Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins (the full code, not the skipped code).

**Edit: I have clarified the rules based on feedback in the comments. The existing answers should still be valid.**

Comment: Is trailing whitespace allowed in the output?

Comment: What precisely counts as an error? Is outputting nothing to STDOUT and something to STDERR sufficient? Consider [this](https://tio.run/##lZDBasMwDIbvfgrhQhxD13bpLZBcxu691zu4TtxkC7ZxMppu7NmzWEuhjC1bDRYSkn99v9/aahicr02ngT6/PCwEFf1mI0M4hKAo5KBfm4acFNwpTGEBrbK@JH1ffPWIO3eVNdswQU91V4F1pYlZaLIl84yDbEGnuCnWK1/KIub7NE2elqUpMsZ42FPJRqMoJuTCJUw2HtiFsjZHkAcF2XSEEYb@fxLu8ygh5P3Cu7auW4cCw8qd0c/HyJLHIwiHZMrwIb9aRCGK4LqclFFRWxsu@vhd7Dv2o/fWB@xZcz9P/W1snuVGY7O/NAyf) potential submission, where the Foo program that "errors" encounters an error that doesn't cause the program to halt, but it has no other output.

Comment: Are we to interpret "run" as "compiled" for compiled languages? Otherwise the implication would be that both shortened and full programs must compile in both languages, but throw run-time errors upon execution if the wrong length.

Comment: Can we output in uppercase (`ABC` instead of `abc`)?

Answer (score 8):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <del>28</del> 26 bytes

```
a+b[c-/[/---<]>>- ]<-.+.+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v8/UTspOllXP1pfV1fXJtbOTlch1kZXTxsI//8HAA)

Got the bf code from [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#97).

Fails in Ink due to Expected target for new thread but saw `'.+.+.'`.

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink)

```
abc//-<>-]-++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v8/MSlZX1/Xxk43Vldb@/9/AA)

Ink will just print `abc` and the rest is a comment.

Fails in brainfuck due to mismatched bracket.

Answer (score 6):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <del>21</del> 19 bytes (<del>19</del> 17 characters)

```
abc#1 / ╘ " a b c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/MSlZ2VBBX@HR1BkKSgqJCkkKyf//AwA)

Simply prints `abc` and the rest is a comment.

Fails in MathGolf due to an undefined operator overload of `/`. `/` can not work on an integer (`1`) and a string( pushed via the space instruction.)

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf)

```
ac1/╘"abc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z8x2VD/0dQZSolJyf//AwA)

Does a bunch of nonsense, then `╘` deletes the whole stack. `"abc` pushes `abc` and the stack has an implicit output.

Fails in Keg due to the failure of implicit-outputting a floating-point number in its character form.

Comment: Welcome to Keg!

Answer (score 5):

## Japt and Pyth, 20 bytes

Both are shortenings of common scripting languages, nice

Japt: `"_a_b_c_"v ë2,1  +[]` ([TIO](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/Xyk@MT4pPjleqUzh8GojHUMFBe3o2P//AQ), [error in Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xyk@MT4pPjleqUzh8GojHUMFBe3o2P//AQ))

Pyth: `"abc" 21 [` ([TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XykxKVlJwchQIfr/fwA), [error in Japt](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XykxKVlJwchQIfr/fwA))

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam) and [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 15 bytes

(CJam only cares about printable ASCII, so Gaia's codepage can be used to encode both programs)

**Full:**

```
 'a'b'c'” 'ọ;e<
```

[Works in CJam](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X0E9UT1JPVn9UcNcBfWHu3utU23@/wcA)

[Errors in Gaia](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/X0E9UT1JPVn9UcNcBfWHu3utU23@/wcA)

**Reduced:**

```
 abc”'ọe
```

[Works in Gaia](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/XyExKflRw1z1h7t7U///BwA)

[Errors in CJam](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/XyExKflRw1z1h7t7U///BwA)

#### Explanation

This takes some advantage of the fact that `'` defines a character literal in both languages.

**Full program:**

We push 5 characters: `a`, `b`, `c`, `”`, and `ọ`. `;` deletes the `ọ` and `e<` leaves the minimum of `c` and `”`, which is `c`. The remaining characters (`abc`) are joined together and output implicitly.

In Gaia, everything up to `”` is a string literal. We then push the char `ọ`, and then copy (`;`) the string literal back to the top and attempt to eval it (`e`). This throws an error because the last character in that string is `'`, which is improper syntax (a character literal after it is expected).

**Reduced program:**

`”` (or, more specifically, byte 0xFB) is not defined, so the program terminates with an error.

In Gaia we get the string literal  `abc` (with leading space). We then push the character `ọ` and eval it, which is the command for trim. This leaves plain `abc` on the stack, which is implicitly output.

Answer (score 5):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz) / [7](http://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 54 bytes

```
6a6a5a5m1a5a1a5a1o5s1a5a1o5s1a5a1o0m3a4a1a2a2a7a4a0a3a
```

This has to be the most esoteric answer I've submitted so far.

**Explanation of the full code** (works in naz)

```
6a6a5a5m1a5a1a5a     # Set the register to a value of 97 ("a")
1o                   # Output once
5s1a5a1o             # Output "b"
5s1a5a1o             # Output "c"
0m3a4a1a2a2a7a4a0a3a # Extra arithmetic to allow for a valid 7 program
```

[Fails in 7](https://tio.run/##M///3yzRLNE00TTXEEiCcb5pMSptkGucaAKUMwJCcyDLINE48f9/AA): `6 command run with no bar in the frame at /opt/7/7.pl line 605, <> chunk 1.`

**The reduced code** (works in 7)

```
665515151515151510341227403
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M///38zM1NQQGRoYmxgaGZmbGBj//w8A)

Fails in naz: `error: attempt to chain number literals`

I can't give a very accurate explanation of the reduced code due to my relatively poor understanding of 7. I invite anyone who can make sense of it to improve this post.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) and [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji), 21 chars, 30 bytes

#### Full:

```php
⛽_a_b_c_➡➡;echo abc;
```

#### Skipped:

```php
⛽abc➡eh b;
```

[PHP, Full - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkH83eG58YnxSfHP9h/qwZj@YtBCLr1OSMfIXEpGTr//8B) Prints: `abc`

[Emoji, Skipped - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///R7L2JSckf5s@a8WjewtQMhSTr//8B) Prints: `abc`

[PHP, Skipped - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkH83em5iU/GH@rBmP5i1MzVBIsv7/HwA) Error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'b' (T_STRING)`

[Emoji, Full - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///R7L3xifFJ8cnxH@bPmvFo3kIgsk5NzshXSExKtv7/HwA) Error: `IndexError: pop from empty list`

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/) and [PHP](https://php.net/), 29 bytes

#### Full:

```javascript
print`abc`;'e_c_h_o_ _a_b_c';
```

#### Skipped:

```php
pitac;echo abc;
```

[JavaScript, Full - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM68kITEpOcFaPTU@OT4jPj9eIT4xPik@Wd36/38A) Prints: `abc`

[PHP, Skipped - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkCzJLEpOtU5Mz8hUSk5Kt//8HAA) Prints: `abc`

[JavaScript, Skipped - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/vyCzJDHZOjU5I18hMSnZ@v9/AA) Error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

[PHP, Full - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkC4oy80oSEpOSE6zVU@OT4zPi8@MV4hPjk@KT1a3//wcA) Error: `abc: command not found`

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) / [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 87 bytes

### Full (C++)

```cpp
//*
#import<cstdio>
main(){puts("abc"/*//
m_a_i_n_(_)_{_p_u_t_s_(_"_a_b_c_"_/*/


) ; }
```

### Skipped (C)

```cpp
/*#motcti>mi({us"b"*/main(){puts("abc"//
);}
```

[Full C++, Working](https://tio.run/##DYrBCoAgEAXv@xViFw1iP6DoVx62QXhQl7RT9O3maZhhRHW5RHpnnmmKScvdNqntjGWnFGJ2/tWnVWfDIZZnZkoIiMhw8HiheNBQh9nRD8jg2IjIm9V8vf8)

[Skipped C++, Error](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/X19LOTe/JLkk0y43U6O6tFgpSUlLPzcxM09Ds7qgtKRYQykxKVlJX59L07r2/38A)

[Full C, Error](https://tio.run/##DYrBCoAgEAXv@xVhFw1iP6DoVx62QXjQJPUkfbvtaZhhZL1FxmBeaA4xP2/dpdQrPAdFH5J1PbdarPGnGF6YKcIjIMHCoSOjoaKoGe0nRKkbEblpm74xfg)

[Skipped C, Working](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19fSzk3vyS5JNMuN1OjurRYKUlJSz83MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEMpMSlZSV@fS9O69v9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

### [Backhand](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Backhand) and [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 39 bytes

#### Full

```
8.cv*c0*~]!]/]:::[@:1[+ooo2o+@o.3.+.o.;
```

[Prints abc in Backhand](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/99CL7lMK9lAqy5WMVY/1srKKtrByjBaOz8/3yhf2yFfz1hPWy9fz/r/fwA)

[Errors in ><>](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30IvuUwr2UCrLlYxVj/Wysoq2sHKMFo7Pz/fKF/bIV/PWE9bL1/P@v9/AA)

#### Skipped

```
8c*0~!/::@1+o2+o3+o;
```

[Prints abc in ><>](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yJZy6BOUd/KysFQO99IO99YO9/6/38A)

[Errors in Backhand](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/98iWcugTlHfysrBUDvfSDvfWDvf@v9/AA)

#### Explanation

Backhand doesn't execute the instructions one by one. In the full version, it goes 3, then the `v` instruction turns it to two steps. In the skipped version, this has the consequence that only the first instruction overlaps with the full version.

When you run the skipped version on Backhand, it divides by zero. Errors in backhand don't stop the program, so I added a stop command, which makes ><> a bit harder. (It's still a command in ><>, just not a good one.)

><>, on the other hand, does not skip instructions. In the full version, a `.` means jump. Fish is a 2D language, so it pops two arguments. However, only 1 thing was pushed (because of `8`). Thus, `something smells fishy...`.

How I get around some of the commands in ><> is simple. When `0` is executed, it pushes 0, then it immediately removes it. Then it skips the next command, which is a mirror. Finally, it duplicates twice, meaning 3 of the same thing is in the stack, which means `@`, which cycles the top 3 items in the stack, does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to CGCC! I hope you enjoy your stay!

Comment: An interesting way of doing it, but both `><>` and Backhand have the `"` operator, which should make it a lot easier to push strings. You can do something like [this](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/19JITk5SSFJITFRQUFJoc4jX0FfIV@hDkxa//8PAA) for 29 bytes, though I'm sure that's easily golfable, perhaps by swapping the two languages

Comment: I only found out about backhand having it after I made this.

Comment: `Errors in backhand don't stop the program`, uhh, they do though

Answer (score 3):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) and [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 85 bytes

**Full**

```
 	 0 _	a	r 1 ; ; ;	;
	
 1 _ b r 2	;	; ; ; ;	; ;
	
 2 _ c * 3	;	; ; ; ;	;	;
	;
 ; ;
```

[Works in Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?474cd92c7d84def46ee832b532f553d9)
[Errors in Whitespace](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X4FTwUAhnjORs0jBUMEaBDmtuTi5gJx4hSSFIgUjTqAATEIBLGUElEpW0FIwRpYC6bLmArG5uLj@/wcA): `Prelude.!!: index too large`

**Reduced**

[Works in Whitespace](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNTAURycXIpKMC4nAqoXIgsFxfX//8A)
[Errors in Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?2f964654cb5cdfa37b7fe83969257d94): `Halted. No rule for state '0' and symbol '_'.`

Takes advantage of the fact that Turing Machine Code ignores most white space and Whitespace pretty much ignores everything else.

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/) / MathGolf, 15 bytes

Here is a golfing language one in *pure* ASCII. (I guess the best score possible is 15 bytes...)

```
"abc"#; " a b c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/XykxKVlJ2VpBSSFRIUkh@f9/AA)

### GolfScript explanation

```
"abc"           # Start a string
     #          # Create a comment (rest is a comment)
      ; " a b c
```

### MathGolf explanation

```
"abc"           Start a string
     #;         Perform expoentiation between the string and the input (implicitly a string)
                This isn't defined yet, so it throws an error
                Discarding the value won't be executed
        " a b c So does this
```

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf)/GolfScript, 8 bytes

```
"b";"abc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18pSclaKTEp@f9/AA)

## MathGolf Explanation

```
"b";     # Push b and then discard the value
    "abc # Push abc and then implicitly print
```

## GolfScript explanation

```
"b";     # Push b and then discard the value
    "abc # Unterminated string, throws an error
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org/) and [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 36 bytes

```
z= print("@ , , , ""a b c "[8: :2] )
```

[Works in Python:](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8pWoaAoM69EQ8lBQQcMlZQSFZIUkhWUoi2sFKyMYhU0//8HAA)

```
z= print("@ , , , ""a b c "[8: :2] )

         "@ , , , "                  #String literal
                   "a b c "          #The second string literal is concatenated to the first
                           [8: :2]   #Extract every other character starting from index 8, which gives us "abc"
   print(                          ) #Print that and return None
z=                                   #Assign the result (None) to the variable z
```

[Errors in Befunge:](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v8pWoaAoM69EQ8lBQQcMlZQSFZIUkhWUoi2sFKyMYhU0//8HAA)

```
z= print("@ , , , ""a b c "[8: :2] )

z     #No-op
 =    #Execute "" (raises an error in both FBBI and PyFunge)
```

### Every other character

```
z rn(@,,,"abc"8 2
```

[Errors in Python](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0qhKE/DQUdHRykxKVnJQsFI4f9/AA)

The code is nowhere close to anything resembling valid Python syntax, so it raises a `SyntaxError`.

[Works in Befunge:](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v0qhKE/DQUdHRykxKVnJQsFI4f9/AA)

```
z rn(@,,,"abc"8 2 

z                  #No-op
  r                #Reverse direction
z                  #No-op
              8 2  #Push 2 and 8 (which we don't care about) onto the stack
         "abc"     #Push "cba" onto the stack
        ,          #Print the top of the stack ("a")
       ,           #Print the top of the stack ("b")
      ,            #Print the top of the stack ("c")
     @             #End the program
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) / [Python 3](https://python.org), 70 bytes

### Full (Rust)

```rust
const _:i8= 3;//1 ; p r i n t ( " a b c " ) #
fn main(){print!("abc")}
```

### Skipped (Python):

```
cnt_i=3/1;print("abc")#f an)pit(ac)
```

Rust fails on the skipped version with

```
error: unexpected closing delimiter: `)`
 --> a.py:1:28
  |
1 | cnt_i=3/1;print("abc")#f an)pit(ac)
  |                            ^ unexpected closing delimiter

error: aborting due to previous error
```

And Python fails on the full version with

```
  File "a.rs", line 1
    const _:i8= 3;//1 ; p r i n t ( " a b c " ) #
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The Rust comment is turned into a division when one of the slashes disappears; the rest is fairly straightforward. I also avoided a compiler warning by naming the useless variable ‘`_`’.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands) / [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)/[bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
"aabbccc"1FÙ;
```

[Try it online in 05AB1E (outputs `abc`)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKTExKSk5OVnJ0O3wTOv//wE).
[Try it online in MathGolf (errors)](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18pMTEpKTk5WcnQ7fBM6///AQ).

Every second character:

```
"abc"F;
```

[Try it online in 05AB1E (errors)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKTEpWcnN@v9/AA).
[Try it online in MathGolf (outputs `abc`)](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18pMSlZyc36/38A).

**Explanation:**

```python
# Full program in 05AB1E:
"aabbccc"     # Push string "aabbccc"
         1F   # Loop 1 time:
           Ù  #  Uniquify the top of the stack
            ; #  Halve it (no-op on strings)
              # (after the loop, the top of the stack is output implicitly)

# Full program in MathGolf:
           Ù  # Errors during compilation, because `Ù` isn't part of its known character-
              # set from the MathGolf codepage

# Reduced program in 05AB1E:
"abc"         # Push string "abc"
     F        # Loop that many times, which results in an error because it isn't an integer

# Reduced program in MathGolf:
"abc"         # Push string "abc"
     F        # Push builtin integer 17
      ;       # Discard the top of the stack
              # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) & [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 29 bytes

```ruby
s=a=y=$> .write  a=?a ,?b ,?c
```

[`abc` in Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9g20bbSVsVOQa@8KLMkVUEh0dY@UUHHPgmIk///BwA),
[error in Perl](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/YNtG20lbFTkGvvCizJFVBIdHWPlFBxz4JiJP///@XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TP0EDPAAA)

This sets the variables `s`, `a` and `y` to the result of `write`ing `a=?a ,?b, ?c` (equivalent to `'abc'` as `?` defines a character literal and `write` accepts multiple arguments) to `$>` (`$>` points to `STDOUT` by default).

```perl
say$ wie =a,b,c
```

[`abc` in Perl](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFoTwzVcE2USdJJ/n//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDfQMAA),
[error in Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vzixUkWhPDNVwTZRJ0kn@f9/AA)

This calls `say` with `$ wie =a,b,c`, which sets `$ wie` to the bareword `a` and  passes the barewords `b` and `c`.